# ImportError: No module named 'httplib'

Tags: python, macos, selenium

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

getting the following error messages

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 23, in <module>
NewjerseyCalifornia
    import http.client as http_client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/asimali/PycharmProjects/Asim/com/introduction/Basics_Selenium.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from selenium import selenium   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 25, in <module>
    import httplib as http_client ImportError: No module named 'httplib' Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note : I also ran the command `2to3 -w Basics_Selenium.py`

Comment: are you using pyton 3 , then use `http.client` instead of this.

Comment: Thanks @AnuradhS but where can i change it ?

Comment: That is a strange error, that should happen only when you are trying to execute python3 script with python2. Are you using `virtualenv` + `pip`? `python3 -m venv env/ && source env/bin/activate && pip install selenium` could fix your issue